# Is HDD recovery possible in this case?

Tags: windows-7, linux, hard-drive, boot, partitioning

I have laptop HP 4320s with seems to be dead disk, but I could get some info from it.
Seems to be dead it is because it isn't seen by BIOS and hence there is no boot from it. But when I'm looking through Linux Mint disk-manager it could see all 3 partitions on it (100 Mb "unpartitioned" and 2 NTFS partitions). But disk-manager shows the errors for these partitions and they could not be mounted.

Any suggestions which tools could be used for recovery of this drive?

P.S. Originally there was Windows 7 installed.

Comment: have you tried putting the HDD in an external enclosure? Are you looking to "recover" the drive to a working state? Or, are you looking to "recover" the data before you dispose and replace it?

Comment: I'd like to revive the drive, but after testing it with TestDrive and BIOS included testing sw I suppose to leave it without active use and only get data from it.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the drive actually contains Windows (NTFS) filesystems, the way I would attempt this would be to:

1. Make a disk image of the drive using [DDRescue](http://www.gnu.org/software/ddrescue/ddrescue.html).
2. Take the original drive and put it in a machine running Windows 7 (maybe
    in an external USB case or similar) and see if that reads the disk.
3. If that did not work I'd look at running Testdisk, failing which photorec.

Comment: I've run TestDisk on this drive, it could read all the filesystems on it. Thank you for the idea.

Answer (score 1):

Another possible way (generally the last step before sending it off to the professionals) would be to try and find another drive with the exact same model number, batch number, serial prefix, etc.  You then MAY be able to swap the circuit boards and recover all of your data that way.

This assumes 2 things:

1. It's a controller board issue and not anything wrong with the motors, platters, or heads.
2. It's a fairly common drive that you could find a duplicate of it relatively easily.

Answer (score 0):

If a disk is broken, maybe (and probably) the data is still there.

The problem is that to extract the data you need to put all the inner plates into a HDD that has it's reading functions working. However, you will never be able to do this stuff at home, since the plates are extremely delicate and only professionals can handle this mechanical data recovery methods.